# MySQLi Num Rows Doesnt Work

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

i have a simple login system and i get nothing when trying to fetch the number of rows, the same method used to work all the time, i dont know what is going on today.

Code:

```
<?php
class LoginClass {
    public $User;
    public $Pass;
    public $Query;
    function Init() {
        $User = $this->User;
        $Pass = $this->Pass;
        if($User != '')
        {
            if($Pass != '')
            {
                $this->HashPass();
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Please Enter A Password.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Please Enter A Username or E-Mail.';
        }
    }

    function HashPass() {
        $Pass = $this->Pass;
        $this->Pass = hash('sha256', $Pass);
        $this->CheckUser();
    }

    function CheckUser() {
        $User = $this->User;
        if(!filter_var($User, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $this->Query = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User = "'.$User.'" AND Pass = "'.$this->Pass.'"';
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Query = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE EMail = "'.$User.'" AND Pass = "'.$this->Pass.'"';
        }
        $this->CheckDB();
    }

    function CheckDB() {
        $Query = $this->Query;
        $Connect = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "Data");
        $Stmt = $Connect->prepare($Query)
        $Stmt->execute();
        $Stmt->store_result();
        echo $Stmt->num_rows;
        $Stmt->close();
        $Connect->close();
    }

    function SetupSession() {
        echo 'Test';
    }
}
```

the Check DB is the problem here and im able to echo out the query variable in that function everything is fine, here is exactly what i get

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User = "Test" AND Pass = "532eaabd9574880dbf76b9b8cc00832c20a6ec113d682299550d7a6e0f345e25"

I also checked my DB and all my tables are setup correctly and there is no password.

Comment: Only hashing a password with SHA256 is not enough. Use [bcrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) instead.

Comment: what is `var_dump($Stmt);` outputting (just before closing)?

Comment: @Marcel - Given that his database has no root password, I doubt this is a production environment.

Comment: @Oshawott: He might easily copy this to a production environment and there are more SO visitors that see this code and think it's ok.

Comment: @bwoebi i dont get anything with a var_dump

Comment: Are you sure that you even enter the if-part? .. When var_dump doesn't output nothing?

Comment: im not sure is there any way to test that?

Comment: @Marcel, this is true. However, SHA256 is hardly the worst thing I've seen people use (how often do we see unsalted MD5?). Salted SHA256 is fairly good. `bcrypt` has performance trade-offs that aren't always worth it, especially on shared or VPS hosting.

Comment: @MoussaHarajli - Test by putting `die('running');` inside the `if` block. If your page dies correctly, the `if` block is being reached.

Comment: What is `var_dump($Connect)` (before the `if` block)? @Oshawott: I don't see a *salted* SHA256.

Comment: @Oshawott nothing happened.

Comment: @Moussa, then the issue (or at least, first issue) is that you're not reaching the `if` block.

Comment: @Oshawott ok, is there any reason for this?

Comment: Possibly your database is down, check for that first.

Comment: i am able to enter phpmyadmin, insert, delete, and update rows in my database i have another form that submits a post, and that works perfectly.

Comment: After the `$Connect` line and before the `if` block try this (will tell you if you have a connection issue):

`if ($Connect->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $Connect->connect_errno . ") " . $Connect->connect_error;
}`

Comment: @Oshawott nothing happens and i also just did a fresh install of windows 8, thats what i have been using before and i have never encountered any problems with it before.

Comment: Do you have `mysqli` extension installed? (If PHP is newer than 5.3 answer is yes)

Comment: @Oshawott i have 5.3.13

Comment: Do `die(var_dump($Query));` after you assign `$Query`.

Comment: @Oshawott i get some html code with the query inside of it.

Comment: Try replacing the `if` block, just assign `$Stmt` then run the code without the block. See if that works.

Comment: @Oshawott Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\Server\www\Assets\PHP\Login\Login.php on line 49

Comment: Update the original post with your updated code please.

Comment: @Oshawott Ok i did it

Answer (score 0):

OK, need more space than the comments area, the issue is clearly in this block:

```
function CheckDB() {
    $Query = $this->Query;
    $Connect = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "Data");
    $Stmt = $Connect->prepare($Query)
    $Stmt->execute();
    $Stmt->store_result();
    echo $Stmt->num_rows;
    $Stmt->close();
    $Connect->close();
}
```

I think it's because you aren't binding parameters to the prepared statement, you've already included them inline in your earlier statement. Therefore, you probably want to:

**Switch to non-prepared statement**

The easy option here will be to switch to a non-prepared statement. Replace your block with:

```
function CheckDB() {
    $Query = $this->Query;
    $Connect = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "Data");
    $Stmt = $Connect->query($Query)
    echo $Stmt->num_rows;
    $Stmt->close();
    $Connect->close();
}
```

A word of caution with this approach: you need to sanitize your user input in the block which defines `$User`, otherwise you're leaving yourself open to mysql injection. In that block, change this line:

```
$User = $this->User;
```

To the following:

```
$User = mysql_real_escape_string($this->User);
```